# How to convert address type to bytes32 via web3?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have contract which require input in bytes32, so I need convert address to bytes32, but no see this method in web3.

Answer (score 12):

Ethereum addresses are 20 bytes, so you convert hex address to bytes and then pad it to 32 bytes from left.

```
web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.hexToBytes(yourAddressString), 32);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [PadLeft documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#padleft), you'd see that you don't need to do any conversion. You simply should do a `web3.utils.padLeft(address, 64`). Given that you want bytes32, that is a total of 64 hex digits, you just need to fill the difference in 0s for in order to have 64 digits.

Comment: For `ethers v6`, you can use `zeroPadValue()` For example ethers.zeroPadValue(0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, 32) to pad the address to a 32 bytes.